# How can i select string/words from input field and click on Bold option at the same time to make string in bold selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bold

I am beginner in selenium using python.

I am automating below web page to learn.
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe

here I am able to enter text in input field successfully.
after that I want to select entered texts and tap on "B" to change format.

## Code:

```
action_chain=ActionChains(self.driver)
inputframe=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.XpathInputFrame)
action_chain.move_to_element(inputframe).perform()
inputframe.send_keys("Hello world") 
format1=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='mce-ico mce-alignright']") 
action_chain.click(format1)
```

please help me how can i change format?

Comment: Please share any code and attempt that you have made on your own first. Thanks!

Comment: action_chain=ActionChains(self.driver) inputframe=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.XpathInputFrame)
action_chain.move_to_element(inputframe).perform() inputframe.send_keys("rkhgaAN/LZJHSKLDJ;MJF\nhsdijdoieuodkjf") format1=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='mce-ico mce-i-alignright']")
action_chain.click(format1)

Comment: @Wanted123 Please edit your post and put your code in your question. The code in comments can easily be overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'mce_0_ifr')))
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body.mce-content-body > p')))
element.clear()
element.send_keys('Hello world')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "A")
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('i.mce-ico.mce-i-bold').click()
```

**Note** : If you using MAC OS, please change `Keys.CONTROL` to `Keys.COMMAND`.

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```